# Как вывести сообщение в запущеном cmd

Tags: c++

Запуск cmd:

```
system("start cmd");
```

Как вывести новые сообщения в запущеном(system) cmd?

Comment: Abyx,вывод информации о состоянии проекта, мне так было бы очень удобно.

Comment: Abyx, могу, но меня заинтересовал именно этот вариант

Comment: Пишите через стандартные потоки ввода-вывода, в чем затруднение?

Comment: @VTT, у меня не консольное приложение

Comment: @0x123 Это не является препятствием для передачи данных в дочерние процессы через стандартные потоки ввода-вывода.

Comment: А что вы хотите в этом запущенном cmd делать? Просто пусть висит открытое окошко?

Comment: Может [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486362/) поможет в решении?